# Discord.py: How to change role color?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, roles

So i created this role for my discord bot and i want to change his color to yellow.
I don't know why it won't change the color. This is my code, can anyone help me with it?

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def add_role(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Spike")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await role.edit(colour=discord.colour(0xFFFF00))
    print("done")
```

edit: It doesn't print the "done"

Comment: Any errors you're getting?

Comment: No errors whatsoever but the color won't change. Also it doesn't print the "done" @ŁukaszKwieciński

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so, my problem was that my bot.command wasn't working because I was using bot and client method at the same time. I wasn't aware that they can't work togheter, so I decided to only use bot, and now everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

On the following line `await role.edit(colour=discord.colour(0xFFFF00))`, it looks like you missed the capitalisation of Colour in the discord class. This should be correct, unless the API already handles this.

`await role.edit(colour=discord.Colour(0xFFFF00))`

Comment: Can you try changing the line to include `name="Spike"` like this `await role.edit(name="Spike", colour=discord.Colour(0xFFFF00))`? I've been looking at similar issues and wonder if that could help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def add_role(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Spike")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await role.edit(colour=0xFFFF00)
    print("done")
```

Comment: So you can try writing `print(1)` under `async def` for checking that command works. If command works, put print() function with a different number after every line and call. With this method, you can understand where the problem is.

Comment: I tried the print("1") under the async def and it doesn't print it. @Weylyn

Comment: Your bot doesn't see this command. And when you called in discord nothing happening.